# vineyard._C.NotEnoughMemoryException

Tags: python, airflow, etl

I'm trying to setup [airflow on vineyardd](https://v6d.io/notes/airflow.html#introducing-airflow) to pass dataframes from one task to another.

However, after some time with vineyard socket running, I'm facing `vineyard._C.NotEnoughMemoryException` which was discussed [here](https://github.com/v6d-io/v6d/issues/586)

despite having default args as

```
default_args = dict(
    owner = DEFAULT_OWNER,
    depends_on_past = False,
    start_date = days_ago(1),
    on_failure_callback = partial(notify_failure_and_cleanup_xcom, users=["fip"])
)
```

where `cleanup_xcom` is

```
from airflow.models import XCom

@provide_session
def cleanup_xcom(context, session=None):
    logging.info(f'Clearing {XCom}')
    dag_id = context["dag"].dag_id
    XCom.clear(dag_id = dag_id)
```

was anyone successful with creating airflow with vineyard xcom backend?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it with

```
@provide_session
def cleanup_xcom(context, session=None):
    for task in context['dag'].tasks:
        try:
            XCom.clear(task_id = task.label, dag_id = context['dag'].dag_id, execution_date = context['execution_date'])
```